# Norms of Quadratic Rings in General and their Factoring

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, quadratics

Let $x$ be any solution to an equation of the form $x^2 + ax + b = 0$, where $a$ and $b$ are integers.

We define any particular set/ring $\textbf Z[x]$ to be all numbers of the form $c + dx$, where $c$ and $d$ are integers. We note that there are two $x$'s. I know from experience that appending one to the integers automatically brings in the other as the two solutions are related by the equation $x = -a - x'$. This leads to the definition of the conjugate for this arbitrary collection of "Quadratic Rings" which each consist of "Quadratic Integers".

> Definition: The Conjugate of a Quadratic Integer $z = c + dx$ is $\bar{z} = c - d(a+x)$

The multiplication of any element and its conjugate is the norm of the Quadratic Integer. This is formalized below.

> Definition: The Norm of a Quadratic Integer $z = c + dx$ is $N(z) = z\bar{z} = c^2 - cda - axd^2 - d^2x^2$.

^^Hopefully I did that multiplication right.

So this leads me to a conjecture based on an earlier question I had that was for the case of $\textbf Z[\sqrt{3}]$:

> Conjecture: If there exists quadratic integers $z$ and $y$ and an ordinary integer $c$, such that $N(z) = N(y)c$, then there exists a quadratic integer $w$ such that $N(w) = c$.

I am seeking a proof of the conjecture that isn't too complex. Rigorous is fine and formality is as well. The problem is that there isn't a whole ton of algebraic number theory knowledge that I have. Primarily I know of integers of rational sets (such as $\textbf Q[x]$), Euclidean domains, modular arithmetic, and what is in this question. So primarily thinking that this question has to do with either solving equations or factoring but I can't quite put my finger on it. I see no reason for it to not be true in the general case, but if it isn't I would like it if someone could say when it is true and perhaps prove that particular case.

Also, I am aware that the norm and conjugate operations distribute across multiplication. Beyond that, I've never looked beyond the $\textbf Z[\sqrt{3}]$ in this rigorous of a sense.

Comment: In general the conjugate of $c+d \sqrt{D}$ is $c-d \sqrt{D}$ and their norm is $c^2-D d^2$.

Comment: Also the norm of $\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}$ is $1$, so you need to take this in account when defining the quadratic integers.

Comment: Just a little notation tidbit: $Z$ can be just about any set, $\textbf Z$ or $\mathbb Z$ is specifically *the* set of integers. Different people have different preferences, so if I assumed the wrong preference for you, I apologize. You can right-click on notation and choose Show Math As -> TeX Commands.

Comment: @Typhon I'm sorry, I assumed you were a new user. I should have known better, I've given away 750 points in bounties, about half of how much you've given away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true in general.
For example consider the case $a=0, b=4$, so $R = \Bbb Z[2i]$

$N(c+dx) = |c+2di|^2 = c^2+4d^2$.

$x = 2i$ has norm $4$, $2+x = 2+2i$ has norm $8$, but there is no element of norm $2$ (because that would require $d=0$ and then $c^2=2$)

However, your conjecture is true if $R$ is integrally closed.

Comment: no it has nothing to do with being real or complex. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_element. In fact I'm almost sure that integrally closed is equivalent to your property. If you find no element of norm $c$ it tells you they are "missing" somehow from your ring.